# Oracle WebCenter Sites JSK deployment on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, fatwire, webcenter-sites

We are thinking about deploying an instance of Oracle Webcenter Sites, at first in JumpStartKit version, using Amazon EC2 services.

I have a couple of questions:

- Are there any incompatibility problems?
- What linux [AMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image) is recommended? library compatibility, etc.

I hope any of you have tried this before...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebCenter Sites is not currently supported on Amazon EC2, although I have heard that technically it is possible, it is not a certified configuration and may not be a trivial task. You can find a spreadsheet of the certified configurations and documentation here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/sites/downloads/index.html

Phil

Answer (score 1):

Webcenter Sites is an CMS application that runs on top of App Servers such as Tomcat, JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere etc., and connects to databases such as HSQLDB, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL etc.,

You should check the cloud offering for related app server and database of your choice.

The JSK runs on Tomcat and connects to HSQLDB but you can always run the installer yourself and configure it to other servers and database.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a vendor who installed WebCenter Sites on AWS for my previous employer with no issues. It is currently powering  the corporate website. We used the Amazon RHEL AMI. I recently spoke with the tech who performed the install and he said there weren't any real 'gotchas'.

I am currently in the process of installing WebCenter sites on an Ubuntu build. I'm not a linux guy so installation is slow going, but so far so good.